# How do the entangled photons behave?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

If I place a linear polarizer at 45° angled with respect to linear axis in front of a KDP crystal then, will the photon pair that the crystal produce be entangled in superposition of linear and horizontal polarizations?

Comment: I'm completely a dilettante in physics I'm studying concepts in physics by my own, I'm posting questions that I want answers for in this web site.